# Program crashes after input

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, while-loop

No errors are reported and program crashes after user input, without advancing through the rest of the functions.

```
def request1():
    responses1 = ["BFR", "Blackfriars", "London Blackfriars", "blackfriars"]
    dep = None
    while dep is None:
        try:
            dep = input(" Where are you travelling from? :")
            dep = str(dep)
        except dep not in responses1:
            print(" Location of departure invalid...")
            continue
        else:   
            real_dep ="BFR"
            print(" Location of departure determined...")
            break
    print(real_dep)

def request2():
    responses2 = ["HSK", "Hassocks", "hassocks"]
    while True:
        try:
            ariv = input(" Where are you travelling to? :")
            ariv = str(ariv)
        except ariv not in responses2:
            print(" Location of arrival invalid...")
            continue
        else:
            real_ariv ="HSK"
            print(" Location of arrival determined... \n Now processing results...")
            break
    print(real_ariv)    

request1()

request2()
```

Please advise on what is causing this error and how I may fix it so this module can be developed and used.

Comment: You say no errors are reported, so what do you mean by *program crashes after user input*?

Comment: Are you by chance running this in a Python 2 interpreter? And as mentioned above, if it's crashing, you are getting errors. If you're running this from a batch file, put a `pause` at the end to see the error.

Comment: you should post what the error is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running the script doesn't show any errors, can you provide more information on when the program is crashing? As asked by other users, how are you running the module?

I removed the items in the lists that are lowercase so that it can be checked in the if-else clause.

```
def request1():
    responses1 = ["BFR", "Blackfriars", "London Blackfriars"]
    while True:
        try:
            dep = input(" Where are you travelling from? :")
            if dep.lower() not in [string.lower() for string in responses1]:
                print(" Location of departure invalid...")
                continue
            else: 
                real_dep ="BFR"  
                print(" Location of departure determined...")
                print(real_dep)
                break
        except:
            print("Failed")

def request2():
    responses2 = ["HSK", "Hassocks"]
    while True:
        try:
            ariv = input(" Where are you travelling to? :")
            if ariv.lower() not in [string.lower() for string in responses2]:
                print(" Location of arrival invalid...")
                continue
            else:
                real_ariv ="HSK"
                print(" Location of arrival determined... \n Now processing results...")
                print(real_ariv) 
                break
        except:
            print("Failed")

request1()

request2()
```